# Monitoring USB traffic

Tags: usb, monitoring

Kernel version: 2.6.31-22

I wish to monitor the USB traffic to and from a device. I've searched, but different sites seem to give different information and I'm confused.

1. Some sites suggest that I need to recompile the kernel, while others suggest that all I need to do is install the latest wireshark. Do I need to recompile?
2. Can someone suggest a website describing the most recent approach to USB sniffing?

Comment: What distribution are you running? Under Ubuntu 10.04 Wireshark has native support for doing a capture on the USB interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to recompile kernel/load module. It is present in 2.6.32 (LTS) kernel - probably 2.6.31 as well. `less /usr/src/linux/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt`. Format is "well known" and it acts like character devince. It can dump in text format as well.

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) [can](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) provide live stream and/or read file from USB as far as GUI is concerned.

Comment: See this answer for steps involved for the wireshark option: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611058/199779