# USB performance/traffic monitor?

Tags: usb, performance, monitoring

First of all, I found a [similar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2354/monitoring-usb-traffic) question but it doesn't really solve my problem. I am trying to discover if the USB bus for a device I am using is the bottleneck in my program.

How can I monitor a USB bus (similar to how gnome-system-monitor works) to show bus utilization? Basically I want to identify when the bus is being 'maxed' out. I guess what I am looking for is some interface for usbmon, as that appears like it would do what I need.

This came about from testing the USRP and GNU Radio. I am running into a situation where it appears that the USB bus could be a limiting factor, so I ask the more general question of USB performance monitoring.

Comment: While wireshark and usbmon get the traffic, I need something that can more easily give me an idea of throughput and such.

Comment: Do you see the usb bus reaching its theoretical maximum? Did you compare the traffic you get with [benchmarks](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/x48-790i-chipset,1940-19.html) of your hardware? Max throughput is usually depended on the device connected and not the system bus, so to test it properly you'll need some hardware specifically made for that purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [usbmon](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt) provides the length of each packet transferred, I would approach this by writing a quick program to parse the `0u` file (which has data for all USB devices.)  It would pick out the USB bus and device numbers, then keep a running total of the packet length field in both directions for each device.

This will then give you the amount of data transferred per device, in each direction.  If you print it once a second you'll get a pretty good idea of each device's throughput.  Note that it won't include any USB overhead, but if you compare the figures to a device that is able to saturate the available bandwidth you'll know whether you're getting close to the limit.

Comment: I was hoping for a pre-existing tool, but I suppose this will be sufficient.

Answer (score 17):

Use [usbtop](https://github.com/aguinet/usbtop), it gives a nice overview of what devices are using how much bandwidth:

```
Bus ID 1 (USB bus number 1) To device   From device
  Device ID 1 :             0.00 kb/s   0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 2 :             0.00 kb/s   0.00 kb/s
Bus ID 2 (USB bus number 2) To device   From device
  Device ID 1 :             0.00 kb/s   0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 4 :             141.73 kb/s 13777.68 kb/s
  Device ID 5 :             9.98 kb/s   11.24 kb/s
  Device ID 6 :             0.00 kb/s   0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 7 :             0.00 kb/s   0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 8 :             141.71 kb/s 15257.26 kb/s
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `usbtop`. It looks useful. Here's how to install it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489268/114401.

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.04 it is in the official repositories, i.e. simply `apt install usbtop`.

Comment: As recalled in other posts, `usbtop` needs the `usbmon` kernel module to be loaded. For instance with `sudo modprobe usbmon`

Answer (score 10):

### 1. usbtop:

As [sebas points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339297/114401), [**usbtop**](https://github.com/aguinet/usbtop) seems to give a certain minimum level of useful information (although it could be much better), so I recommend it.

[image]

#### Here's how to install it (build `usbtop` from source code):

1. Clone the git repo:

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/aguinet/usbtop.git
   ```
2. Navigate to the directory that just got created from `git clone`:

   ```bash
   cd usbtop
   ```
3. Install dependencies:

   ```bash
   sudo apt update 
   sudo apt install \
       libboost-dev \
       libpcap-dev \
       libboost-thread-dev \
       libboost-system-dev \
       cmake \
       build-essential
   ```
4. Create local build directory & cd into it:

   ```bash
   mkdir _build && cd _build
   ```
5. Run cmake to prepare to build usbtop from source:

   ```bash
   cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
   ```
6. Build usbtop from source:

   ```bash
   make
   ```
7. Install usbtop:

   ```bash
   sudo make install
   ```
8. Load the usbmon kernel module to open access to USB buses (I think this is what that does, but I know it's required):

   ```bash
   sudo modprobe usbmon
   ```
9. Run usbtop (if this doesn't work, use `sudo usbtop` instead):

   ```bash
   usbtop
   ```

If I missed anything let me know in the comments.

#### Install References:

- https://github.com/aguinet/usbtop/blob/master/INSTALL
- https://github.com/aguinet/usbtop/issues/3#issuecomment-274325720

### 2. Update: You can also use `iostat` instead:

```bash
sudo apt install sysstat
```

Run at 1-second intervals with:

```bash
iostat -d 1
```

OR with 0.1-second intervals with:

```bash
watch -n 0.1 iostat
```

Sample output of `iostat -d 1`:

[image]

#### References:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/3561/how-do-i-monitor-disk-activity-on-a-specific-drive

### Additional reading:

https://www.znetlive.com/blog/monitor-disk-io-windows-linux/

### Related:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/276669/how-to-monitor-disk-activity
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/436354/how-to-check-the-disk-activity-of-my-hard-drive
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/87035/how-to-check-hard-disk-performance

Comment: For the first solution, you missed a dependency: `sudo apt  install cmake`

Comment: Thanks. I just added it!

Comment: the second solution shows gibberish results https://www.toolbox.com/collaboration/team-collaboration/question/problem-understanding-iostat-reported-on-luns-110804/

Comment: `iostat` would be so much better if it just kept a sum of the amount copied, and rewrite over the previous value, instead of creating additional lines!

Comment: Note if the cmake is failing you might need to `sudo apt install build-essential`

Comment: @JoseRocha, thanks. I added that to the answer as one of the dependencies to install.

Answer (score 2):

I've wrote a pair of shell scripts to get the throughput from a USB device. If someone what to use it, you can find it in this [post](http://pipe.oliveira-carvalho.com/blog/tech/monitorusbthroughput).

Comment: [Links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers#answer-8259)

Comment: Scripts are based on `usbmon` which needs to be installed/compiled(?) manually.

Answer (score 1):

Using `htop`, I pressed `F2` for `Setup`, selected columns, added `IO_READ_RATE`, `IO_WRITE_RATE` or `IO_RATE`, and i was able to see the speed at which processes were reading or writing from and to disks.

Comment: This question is about USB traffic though, not disk traffic (e.g. how much bandwidth a USB webcam uses.)

Answer (score 1):

For the wireshark option:

1. Make sure usbmon is running

   ```
   sudo modprobe usbmon
   ```
2. Run wireshark

   ```
   sudo wireshark # may or may not requiring sudoing
   ```
3. Identify the correct USB interface (usbmonX) and start the capture
4. In the top menu, Statistics --> I/O Graph
5. Filter the display for the USB packets (or just leave empty to measure all USB packets)
6. Set Y Axis to Bytes

You can compare the bytes/s with the max speed of USB2.0 or USB3.0 depending on your USB interface.